# ValueError: could not convert string to float, Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, feature-extraction, valueerror

I have a dataframe on which i'm trying to implement feature selection. 
There are 45 columns of types, integer, float and object.

But I'm unable to fit any feature selection model since its throwing vale Error. Please help me out

Dataframe :

```
member_id   loan_amnt   funded_amnt funded_amnt_inv term        batch_enrolled   int_rate   grade
58189336    14350       14350       14350           36 months                    19.19      E
70011223    4800        4800        4800            36 months   BAT1586599       10.99      B

 sub_grade  emp_title   emp_length  home_ownership  annual_inc  verification_status pymnt_plan  desc                purpose title      zip_code addr_state   dti
 E3         clerk       9 years     OWN             28700       Source Verified     n           debt_consolidation  Debt consolidation 349xx    FL        33.88
 B4         HR          < 1 year    MORTGAGE        65000       Source Verified     n           home_improvement    Home improvement    209xx   MD      3.64

 last_week_pay  loan_status
 44th week          0
 9th week           1
```

Code:

```
 import numpy
 from pandas import read_csv
 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
 # load data
 df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/anagha/Documents/Python  Scripts/train_indessa.csv")
 array = df.values
 X = array[:,0:44]
 Y = array[:,44]
 # feature extraction
 pca = PCA(n_components=3)
 fit = pca.fit(X)
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-8-20f3863fd66e>", line 2, in <module>
 fit = pca.fit(X)

 File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-  packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 301, in fit
self._fit(X)

File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 333, in _fit
copy=self.copy)

File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '44th week'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to convert a string like '44th week' to float.

The only part from the string python could actually convert is 44. In order to do so i would recommend altering the string in order to keep exclusively numbers. Afterwards, you will easily apply sklearn fit.  The following code should show how to get your np array ready to convert to float.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['rows','col1','Col2','Col_withtext'],
            ['Row1',1,2,'44th week'],
            ['Row2',3,4,'the 30th week']])


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
              index=data[1:,0],
              columns=data[0,1:])
```

## Use pandas replace to remove text

```
df['Col_withtext'].replace(to_replace="[a-zA-Z]", value='', 
regex=True, inplace=True)

df.values
```

##prints out

```
 array([['1', '2', '44 '],
   ['3', '4', ' 30 ']], dtype=object)
```

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fit PCA on a non-numeric data. PCA involves matrix decomposition, and since some of your data is not numeric, you cannot apply PCA on it. So in order to proceed with PCA you should either ignore non-numeric columns , or transforming them into numeric columns.

Comment: If not PCA, can you use anything else for non-numerical data? 
I have tried lcouple of approach, but everything seems to work for Non-Numerical. 

can you suggest how to go about when I have Non-numerical data and apply feature selection on it

Comment: You can start from converting things like "36 months" to 36, and in addition if you have columns with small number of categories, you can encode them into numbers. You may try to ignore columns that are hard to encode, like "desc" (if there are many possible categories), and see whether the results that you get are good enough.

Comment: Those columns might be important for my prediction. So there is no way I can do feature selection on Non-numerical data? It needs to be always numerical?

Comment: In such case I would suggest to use other things instead of PCA. You can try to use random forests for example https://chrisalbon.com/machine-learning/feature_selection_using_random_forest.html. But before choosing a particular method, check if sklearn (or any other package that you intend to use) supports non-numeric values. Sometimes even if the algorithm allows such values, the packages do not support them.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thank you